# Phase space density behavior in finite volume

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory, software

I am trying to develop better intuition for the single-particle phase space density $f(x,v,t)$ and I am confused by the tendency of $f(x,v,t)$ to become wiggly in velocity space. Consider the simplest possible situation of non-interacting particles on the interval $[0,L]$ with periodic boundary conditions. If we consider the initial phase space density ($|A|<1$)
$$f_0(x,v) = \frac{1+A\cos(k_1 x)}{L}\frac{e^{-\frac{v^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}$$
where $k_n = (2\pi/L)n$, then according to the non-interacting Vlasov equation $\partial f/\partial t + v \partial f /\partial x = 0$, the phase space density is given by $f(x,v,t) = f_0(x-vt,v)$. Marginalizing over velocity space one finds that the number density decays exponentially to a constant,
$$\rho(x,t) = \frac{1+A\cos(k_1 x)e^{-\frac{1}{2}k_1^2\sigma^2 t^2}}{L} \longrightarrow \frac{1}{L}$$
whereas the conditional velocity density $f(x,v,t)/\rho(x,t)$ oscillates wildly as a function of $v$ as $t\to\infty$. How can one understand this behavior intuitively?

Below I include a plot of the conditional velocity density (conditioned on $x=0$) at time $t=0$ and $t=4$ and the Mathematica code used to generate it.

[image]

```
\[Sigma]=1;L=1;a=0.3;
k[n_]:=(2Pi/L)n;
f[x_,v_,t_]:=(1+a Cos[k[1](x-v t)])/L Exp[-v^2/(2\[Sigma]^2)]/Sqrt[2Pi \[Sigma]^2];
\[Rho][x_,t_]:=(1+a Cos[k[1]x]Exp[-(1/2)k[1]^2\[Sigma]^2t^2])/L
x=0;
Plot[{f[x,v,0]/\[Rho][x,0],f[x,v,4]/\[Rho][x,4]},{v,-3,3},AxesLabel->{Style["v",Italic],""}, LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 16,SingleLetterItalics -> True},PlotLegends->"Expressions"]
```

Comment: It does not seem that your equation for $f(x,v,t)$ is consistent with the periodic boundary conditions. That might be the solution for the unbounded process.

Comment: @Javi, it’s consistent. Note that the periodicity is only wrt $x$.

Comment: I insist that there is a problem. The equation allows for having a non-zero density for positions outside the interval $[0,L]$. For example, when $x=2L$, $v$ is arbitrary, and $t=\frac{2L}{v}$, we have $f(2L,v,\frac{2L}{v}) = f_0(0,v) \neq 0$.

Comment: For any fixed $t \in \mathbb{R}$, the function $f(x,v,t)$ is a normalized probability density on $[0, L] \times \mathbb{R}$, which satisfies the boundary condition $f(0, v, t)=f(L, v, t)$, the initial condition $f(x,v,0)=f_0(x,v)$ and the PDE. I don’t see what else you could want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a picture of your initial phase-space density. Position is the horizontal axis and velocity is the vertical. I've also included plots of the velocity distribution (left) and the spatial density (bottom).
[image: a circle]

The intuition to have is that each fixed-velocity horizontal slice (row) "slides" to the left or right, at the rate corresponding to its velocity, while remaining otherwise unaltered. Here's the phase-space density a short time later. Due to the "sliding" of the horizontal slices (rows), the initial nearly circular distribution is sheared to the left and right.
[image: circle sheared to the left and right]

After a much longer time, the phase-space density looks like this. The initial distribution is sheared nearly into a line, and due to the periodicity, it loops back on itself. This is where the oscillatory behavior is coming from. The distribution that you plotted above is essentially a vertical slice (column) of this.
[image: circle sheared nearly into a diagonal line]

#### [**Here's a link to the movie.**](https://youtu.be/KmlYJ_nlzTc)

A long time afterward, the phase-space density looks like this:
[image: line that loops back many times, nearly horizontal]